# How can I create a table from key-value pairs?

Tags: attributes

I want to check the differences between lots of key value pairs. I know I could write some code to do this, but I feel there is going to be an easier way to accomplish this. These values come from HTTP request URLs.

Say I have the following key value pairs, they are not always in order:

Set 1:

```
a=1
b=2
c=3
```

Set 2:

```
a=2
c=5
b=7
```

Set 3:

```
b=5
c=2
a=8
```

Set 4:

```
a=1
c=6
b=7
```

I'm looking for an output like this, just so I can easily see differences:

[image: The output I'm looking for]

How can I achieve this easily, without having to write my own program?

Comment: This question is off topic here, asking for product / service / learning material recommendation. Please read what's [on-topic here](http://superuser.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `awk` for this:

```
cat file1 file2 | awk -F "=" '{i[$1]=(i[$1] " " $2)} END {for (key in i) { print key " " i[key]}}'
```

Example output:

```
d  104 42
a  8 9
b  9 13
c  22 -1
```

Additionally pipe to `sort` if you want the values in a consistent order.

Comment: Perfect, thanks! I never even thought to use *nix!

Comment: Please don't answer off-topic questions.

Comment: I didn't think it was too off-topic when I wrote my answer. I just assumed that by "application" he meant "some combination of Linux tools". Apparently he actually did mean "application"!

Comment: Agreed, the user just had a problem they wanted to solve. It's easy enough to fix the question to “how can I do …?” cc @DavidPostill

Comment: @slhck Fair point. CV removed. ;p